# SwiftUI: how to clear value in DatePicker?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to clear a value of a DatePicker in SwiftUI. I tried and it's not successful. Here is the code:

```
struct EditProfileView: View {
   
    @State var birthDate = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section (header: Text("Birth day")) {
                DatePicker(selection: $birthDate, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date) {
                    Text("Select a date")
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("You were born in \(birthDate, formatter: dateFormatter)")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        self.clearDate()
                    }) {
                        Text("Clear")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func clearDate () {
        self.$birthDate = nil
    }
    
}
```

This line of code is not working:

`self.$birthDate = nil`

I think because of Date type can't not leave `nil` but I can't find a solution to handle it.

Comment: what you mean by clear date? better give screenshot before and after... we need screenshot for expected result...

Answer (score -1):

Set the `birthDate` (not `$birthDate`) to the following, which will default back to the current date:

```
self.birthDate = Date()
```

Comment: But I want to clear it, because this input can be leave without value

Comment: @KitKit There's no such thing as clearing a `DatePicker` control.

Answer (score -2):

You can create a Binding from Date?

```
  struct EditProfileView: View {

            @State var birthDate : Date?

            var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
                           let formatter = DateFormatter()
                           formatter.dateStyle = .short
                           return formatter
                         }

            var body: some View {
                Form {
                    Section (header: Text("Birth day")) {
                        DatePicker(selection: Binding<Date>(get: { () -> Date in
                            self.birthDate ?? Date()
                        }, set: { (Date) in
                            self.birthDate = Date
                        }), in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date) {
                            Text("Select a date")
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Text( "You were born in :") + (birthDate == nil ? Text("") :  Text("\(birthDate!, formatter: dateFormatter)"))
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                            Spacer()
                            Button(action: {
                                self.clearDate()
                            }) {
                                Text("Clear")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            func clearDate () {
                self.birthDate = nil
            }

          }
```